# Looping script with Zonal Statistics

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, loop, for-loop

This is my first time using python in ArcGIS. I have a gdb of about 100 feature classes, and need to get Zonal Statistics for each. I'm using a textbook, and got this so far:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = 'D:\Documents\Archaeology\Dissertation\Data\GIS\Places_Bounds\Places\Exploded_Bilinear\Argolid.gdb'
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses ("ID_*")
for fclist: 
    arcpy.sa.ZonalStatistics ("fclist", "place_id", "pelop1arcm34b", "MEAN", "NODATA")
```

The error is coming from line 6. I am assuming my trouble is defining the input for the zonal statistics -- I want it to refer to the geodatabase set in the workspace, and loop through the whole dataset (about 100 feature classes). For reference: place_id is the unique identifier, and pelop1arcm34b is the DEM.

Comment: You should add an r in front of the path. Otherwise the backslashes can cause problems. For example `r'C:\database.gdb'`. So the DEM is located in the workspace database and all the feature classes have the same zone field name?

Answer (score 3):

I corrected your code for you. After each line you find a comment to show you what was corrected. Also reading about [about for loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), the [range](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) and [len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) functions can help you understand the changes.

```
import arcpy
#from arcpy import env #this line can be removed
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\Documents\Archaeology\Dissertation\Data\GIS\Places_Bounds\Places\Exploded_Bilinear\Argolid.gdb' #called arcpy.env
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("ID_*") #removed whitespace
for i in range(len(fclist)): #corrected your loop
    outraster = arcpy.sa.ZonalStatistics (fclist[i], "place_id", "pelop1arcm34b", "MEAN", "NODATA") #corrected reference to the items you are iterating over by retrieving it from the fclist by its index
    outraster.save("outraster" + str(i)) #save the outputraster with the name 'outraster1' 'outraster2' etc.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72803/discussion-on-answer-by-lmb-looping-script-with-zonal-statistics).